# Reducing Canvas html code for charts in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, charts, angular-chart

For displaying charts I'm using the module [angular-chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/). The Angular app needs two kind of charts, the bar-chart and line-chart. Currently the charts are separatly defined in the HTML view.

Following you can see the currently code:

```
<canvas id="bar"
        height="120"
        ng-show="showBarChart"
        class="chart chart-bar" 
        chart-data="dataChart"
        chart-labels="labels"
        chart-series="series">
</canvas>

<canvas id="line cvs-size"
        height="120"
        ng-show="showLineChart" 
        class="chart chart-line" 
        chart-data="dataChart"
        chart-labels="labels"
        chart-series="series">
</canvas>
```

The following code below is the required target:

```
<canvas id="{{ chartType }}"
        height="120"
        ng-show="showChart"
        class="chart chart-{{ chartType }}" 
        chart-data="dataChart"
        chart-labels="labels">
</canvas>
```

The user has the possibility to choose a query. Clicking on the button returns the corresponding chart for the query.

```
CrudService.getData(from, to).$promise.then(
    function (resp) {
      $scope.showChart = true;
      $scope.chartType = 'bar';
      angular.forEach(resp, function (item) {
          $scope.labels.push(item.fname);
          $scope.data.push(item.age);
      });
      $scope.dataChart = [$scope.data];
    });
```

The request was sent and an answer was returning successfully. But the chart doesn't displayed in the view.. I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular doesn't support setting the class dynamically for directives. You will have to use the [base](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#base-chart) chart and set the `type` dynamically.

Comment: that means when I set the `chart-type` for example to `line` then I will get the line chart in the view?

Comment: many thanks.. I've been overlooked the dynamically part on the github site :)